# Unable to upload image with parameters using alamofire 4?

Tags: image, file-upload, alamofire, ios10, swift3

While uploading an image with parameters using alamofire 4 getting the following:

```
Alamofire.DefaultDataResponse(request: url, response: Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17523cde0> { URL: rl} { status code: 409, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 32;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Tue, 04 Apr 2017 20:23:50 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.8.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.60";
    Status = "409 Conflict";
    Vary = Origin;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Phusion Passenger 4.0.60";
    "X-Request-Id" = "4bd65f3e-9cae-4f69-8d5f-139dfed6c148";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.490166"; } }), data: Optional(32 bytes), error: nil, timeline: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 513030074.617, "Initial Response Time": 513030127.999, "Request Completed Time":
513030230.298, "Serialization Completed Time": 513030230.303, "Latency": 53.382 secs, "Request Duration": 155.681 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.005 secs, "Total Duration": 155.686 secs }, _metrics: Optional((Task Interval) <_NSConcreteDateInterval: 0x17163b000> (Start Date) 2017-04-04 20:21:14 +0000 + (Duration)
155.679614 seconds = (End Date) 2017-04-04 20:23:50 +0000 (Redirect Count) 0 (Transaction Metrics) (Request) <NSURLRequest: 0x170202da0> { URL: url } { status code: 409, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 32;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Tue, 04 Apr 2017 20:23:50 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.8.1 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.60";
    Status = "409 Conflict";
    Vary = Origin;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Phusion Passenger 4.0.60";
    "X-Request-Id" = "4bd65f3e-9cae-4f69-8d5f-139dfed6c148";
    "X-Runtime" = "0.490166"; } } (Fetch Start) 2017-04-04 20:22:07 +0000 (Domain Lookup Start) 2017-04-04 20:22:07 +0000 (Domain Lookup End) 2017-04-04 20:22:07 +0000 (Connect Start) 2017-04-04 20:22:07
+0000 (Secure Connection Start) (null) (Secure Connection End) (null) (Connect End) 2017-04-04 20:22:07 +0000 (Request Start) 2017-04-04 20:22:07 +0000 (Request End) 2017-04-04 20:23:48 +0000 (Response Start) 2017-04-04 20:23:50 +0000 (Response End) 2017-04-04 20:23:50
+0000 (Protocol Name) http/1.1 (Proxy Connection) NO (Reused Connection) NO (Fetch Type) Network Load
```

Didn't understand anything. Image is not uploading but getting those response. Please help if anyone faced such kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to sent the parameters as a body but trying it by default which not a body request causing the error.